# Adding url dynamically in jwplayer javascript using drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I am using `file_create_url` function in my custom menu for particular node video field. i want to load this url in jquery jwvideo player file path dynamically under below this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".field-item.even img").click(function()
   {
     var basepath = Drupal.settings.basePath;
     alert(basepath);   

     var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
     playerInstance.setup({
      image: "http://localhost/drupal742/sites/default/files/mypics/index1.jpeg",
      file: "http://localhost/drupal742/sites/default/files/mypics/ameex.mp4",
      title: "My Cool Trailer",
        height: 300,
        weight: 300,
        //flashplayer: 'player.swf',
        primary: 'html5',
       events: {
         onReady: function(){alert('im ready')},
         onPlay: function(){alert('lets play')}
         }
 }); 
});
});
```